# In Open Office, make 1st row of data "scroll lock" so it is always visible as you scroll down?

Tags: openoffice, spreadsheet

In Open Office, how do you make the first row of data "scroll lock" so it is always visible as you scroll down?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Select the first row below that which you would like "frozen" and select Window | Freeze.

EDIT: In fact, this works to freeze rows and columns.  For example, if select cell C3 and Window | Freeze, then the first two rows and the first two columns will be frozen.

Comment: For `gnumeric` users, a similar feature is available through [View > Freeze Panes](http://www.hep.by/gnu/gnumeric/View-Menu.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Or do it in one step by putting your cursor in the first cell that you want to allow to change, then click Window > Freeze.

For example, to freeze the first two rows and the first two columns, you'd put your cursor in cell C3 and click Window > Freeze.